# Sequelize: set new uuid

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How do I set a new uuid to a model every time it's called?

ex:

```
User.find({where: true})
    .then(function(user) {
        user.changingUUID = new UUID
        return user.save();
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

For those who might need it:

```
var sequelize = require('sequelize');
User.find({where: true})
.then(function(user) {
    user.changingUUID = sequelize.Utils.generateUUID()
    return user.save();
});
```

For those who are interested in seeing how it's implemented in sequelize:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/18cb700291fe519f2c77dd91d1e3504acae4b233/lib/utils.js#L652

Seeing this, I decided to use [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) instead.

Comment: Looks like Sequelize has removed the `generateUUID()` utility method, and started using `node-uuid` for default UUID values https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/utils.js#L8

Comment: Use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) instead, as long as i know it works faster with zero dependencies